# Route does not exist when redirecting to resource route [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes, resources

I have the following Route defined:

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController', ['except' => ['create', 'destroy']]);
```

However, when I try and redirect to the profile/{id} method using the following:

```
redirect()->route('profile', [$userId]);
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 278:
Route [profile] not defined.
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route method takes a route name as the first argument. All specific resource routes will get their own names, however there's none created with the name of the base resource (profile).

By running `php artisan route:list` you will see a list of all routes along with their names. For you it should look something like this:

```
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                     | Name            | Action                                            | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | profile                                 | profile.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@store      |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | profile                                 | profile.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@index      |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | profile/create                          | profile.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@create     |            |
|        | PATCH    | profile/{profile}                       |                 | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update     |            |
|        | PUT      | profile/{profile}                       | profile.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update     |            |
|        | DELETE   | profile/{profile}                       | profile.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@destroy    |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | profile/{profile}                       | profile.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@show       |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | profile/{profile}/edit                  | profile.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@edit       |            |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

So since it seems you are intending to **show** a user profile, this should be what you are looking to do:

```
redirect()->route('profile.show', [$userId]);
```

Comment: That's perfect. I've changed this to the answer as using the `->route()` method seems far cleaner than `redirect('/profile/' . $id`).

Answer (score 1):

Try redirect this way

```
return redirect('profile/2');
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't seem to redirect at all. Does it matter if I'm doing this in the index method of ProfileController? I'm trying to set it up so /profile shows the logged in users profile and /profile/{id} shows someone else's.

Comment: Actually, yep this code worked. It was my fault as I wasn't returning the redirect.

Comment: if this code worked make this up vote.It will helpful for others